# Messages Queue C multiple processes

Tags: c, process, fork, message-queue, message

I've experiencing issues with messages after forking a child process.
basically the father needs to create a messages queue and a child process and then pause till the child send a message and terminate. After that the father read the message.
IT gives me both read and write error when executed.
Thanks for the help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

typedef struct Mymsg {
    long mtype;/* Message type */
    char mtext[20]; /* Message body */
}Mymsg;


int main() {
    int mask, id;
    key_t key;
    mask = 0666;
     Mymsg message;
    Mymsg in;
    key = ftok("/tmp", 'x');
    if((id = msgget(key, IPC_CREAT)) == -1) {
        printf("msgget error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    switch(fork()) {
        case 0:
            printf("CHILD PROCESS\n");
            message.mtype=1;
            strcpy(message.mtext,"test");
            if(msgsnd(id,&message,sizeof(message.mtext),0)==-1)
                printf("ERROR SEND\n");

            _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        default:
            wait(NULL);
            printf("FATHER PROCESS\n");
            if(msgrcv(id, &in, (sizeof(in)- sizeof(long)), 1,0)== -1)
                printf("ERROR RCV \n");
            printf("READ: %s\n", in.mtext);
            msgctl(id, IPC_RMID,0);
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

    }
```

Comment: Use `perror()` when you get an error from a system call, so you can see the reason for the error.

Comment: Could you please run this [cleaned up version with diagnostics](https://pastebin.com/saWWjcY9) and provide the output?

Comment: Thanks for the help,, here's the output:  [child] msgsnd: Permission denied
[parent] Child exited with error 1

Comment: It looks like  msgget() returns  id=0 and the send functions fails for this reason.. very strange. PS: i'm coding on virtual machine